# Is there a way to positionate InfoWindow in osmdroid bonuspack?

Tags: android, dictionary, positioning, marker, osmdroid

My code:

```
Marker startMarker = new Marker(mMapView);
startMarker.setPosition(VBA.getPosition());
startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_hotel1));
startMarker.setTitle(VBA.getHotelName());
startMarker.setRelatedObject(null);
startMarker.setInfoWindow(new CustomInfoWindow(mMapView, startMarker));
mMapView.getOverlays().add(startMarker);
```

My CustomInfoWindow

```
public class CustomInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {

    ...SOME ATTRIBUTES....

    public CustomInfoWindow(MapView mapView,Marker marker) {
        super(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble_edited, mapView);

        ...OTHER CODE...

    }
```

[Click here to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uMo6.png)

I would like to distantiate the bubble from the marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put layout_marginBottom on R.layout.bonuspack_bubble_edited